# Reverse proxy from the path to the desired address

Tags: linux, server, reverse-proxy, traefik

reverse proxy from the path to the desired address
I am going to reverse proxy `domainone.com/blog/` to `https://domaintwo.com`. The goal is to transform incoming requests as follows:

```
domainone.com/blog/ =>  https://domaintwo.com
domainone.com/blog/seo/ =>  https://domaintwo.com/seo/
domainone.com/blog/article/product/ =>  https://domaintwo.com/article/product/
```

But the settings I applied in config.yml are not working properly.

```
http:
  routers:
    novu_api_router:
      rule: "Host(`domainone.com`) && Path(`/blog/`)"
      service: "novu_api_service"
      entryPoints:
        - "https"
        - "http"
      tls:
        options: default
        certresolver: mycert

  services:
    novu_api_service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "https://domaintwo.com"



tls:
  options:
    default:
      minVersion: VersionTLS12
      maxVersion: VersionTLS13
      cipherSuites:
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305 
        - TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384               
        - TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
  certificates:
    - certFile: /traefik/certs/fullchain.pem
      keyFile: /traefik/certs/privkey.pem
```

Currently, the requests are incorrectly based on the config.yml above as follows:

```
domainone.com/blog/ =>  https://domaintwo.com/blog/
domainone.com/blog/seo/ =>  https://domaintwo.com/blog/seo/
domainone.com/blog/article/product/ =>  https://domaintwo.com/blog/article/product/
```

Please guide me. I have been searching on Google and asking questions from chatgpt for almost 4 days, but my problem is not solved.